# ellipsoid and the solution of underdetermined system

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, linear-transformations

Say $X$ is a fat data matrix (s by n, where each row is a sample). The relationship between $X$ and and $Y$ (s by m output matrix) is

$$Y=XW$$

With pseudo-inverse, $W$ is expressed as

$$X(XX^T)^{-1}Y=W$$

Then $W^TW$ (m by m) is

$$ Y^TK^{-1}Y=W^TW $$

where $K=XX^T$.

I am trying to interpret this expression in terms of Gaussian distribution and ellipsoid. In the case where $W$ is white noise, $W^TW=I$, which means that each column of $Y$ will have a Gaussian distribution with covariance $K$ in $s$ dimensional space.

However, what confuses me is the case where $Y$ is given, along with $X$. In that case what does the $W^TW$ say about the statistics of $W$?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $X$ is "normalized" so that its rows have zero mean. I am not sure if this assumption is appropriate for your context.

With that said, here is a possibly helpful line of reasoning. There exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $K^{-1} = P^TP$. Note that the covariance matrix $X^TX$ has eigenvalues equal to the variance of its principal components along with some extra $0$ eigenvalues. On the other hand, the eigenvalues of
$$
M = X^T(XX^T)^{-1}X = (PX)^T(PX)
$$
are all equal to $0$ and $1$. In other words, we can interpret $P$ as a transformation of the data that equalizes the variance of $X$ along its principal components.

Finally, note that
$$
W^TW = Y^TK^{-1}Y = (PY)^T(PY).
$$
With that established, perhaps $W^TW$ can be interpreted as encoding the statistics of $Y$ "relative to" the statistics of $X$.